# PGFPlots option to include/ignore data set when determining axis limits?

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to tell pgfplots whether or not to consider individual data sets when automatically determining axis limits, or call some sort of "maintain axes limits at their current values from now on" command?

Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%
    \addplot coordinates { (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) };%Automatically sizes axes (want)
    \addplot coordinates { (0,1) (1,4) };%Automatically re-sizes axes (don't want)
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The application is plotting experimental results vs. simulation --- I want both data sets to be plotted always, but I'd like the experimental data to set the scale, even if the simulation results are extremely different.

I recognize that I could go through and hard-code a reasonable scale myself, but this is for a script that I'm running in batch mode with many different data sets, so it would be more convenient if I didn't have to write a whole other family of scripts for choosing reasonable axis limits.